# "afterBulkCreate" Hook in sequelize always returns latest values in the _previousDataValues when using updateOnDuplicate which updates certain column

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

```js
  Table.addHook('afterBulkCreate' , async (params , options) => {
    console.log("Table.afterBulkCreate ~ params:", params , options)
  })

  const st1 = await Table.bulkCreate(params, {
      updateOnDuplicate: ["metrics", "status" ]
    })
```

The `dataValues` , `_previousDataValues` are similar also `_changed: Set(0) {},` is an empty set. Eventhough the rows got updated correctly.

I tried using `individualHooks: true` which gives seperate hooks but still no previous values. May be `bulkCreate` won't give `previousValues` which updated using `DUPLICATE KEY`. I also tried using `afterUpdate` Hooks , This hook is not fired.

I am trying to create a Audit log for previous and current values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beforeBulkCreate` hook in which you can make a find query to your table to get the previous values.

```
Table.beforeBulkCreate(async (params,options) => {
  const previousRecords = await Table.findAll();
})
```